# Extract text across HTML tags as a single string

Tags: html, python-3.x, web-scraping

I'm trying to extract the text content from the HTML code below as a complete sentence however I am not able to. I tried using both `Beautifulsoup.prettify()` and `Beautifulsoup.get_text()` but those gave me 3 sentences. I would like to read the HTML below as a single proper sentence like

> Recognized by Microsoft & Google, Inc., offices.

```html
<li>Recognized by   
                                    <em>Microsoft</em> &amp; 
                                    <em>Google, Inc.</em>, offices.</li>
```

Comment: What is your code?

Comment: Is there a source url? I assume there are other li with child em in source. Should this happen only once? For a repeated pattern?

Answer (score 0):

You can use an HTML parser like BeautifulSoup to extract the text without tags (`soup.text`), then strip the text of duplicate whitespaces/newlines etc:

```
input_str = '''
<li>Recognized by   
                                    <em>Microsoft</em> &amp; 
                                    <em>Google, Inc.</em>, offices.</li>
'''

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(input_str,"html.parser")
text = " ".join(soup.text.split())
print(text)
```

Output:

```
Recognized by Microsoft & Google, Inc., offices.
```

---

Edit: based on your comments, in order to get a list of strings as an output (one for each `li` tag, you can do:

```
input_str = '''<ul> <li>This is sentence one in a order</li> <li>This is sentence two in a order</li> <li>This is sentence <em>Three</em> in a order </li> <li>This is sentence <em>four</em> in a order </li> </ul>'''

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(input_str,"html.parser")

result = []
for li in soup.find_all('li'):
    text = " ".join(li.text.split())
    result.append(text)

print(result)
```

Output:

```
['This is sentence one in a order', 'This is sentence two in a order', 'This is sentence Three in a order', 'This is sentence four in a order']
```

Comment: Does my solution work for you? Or is there an issue? My code outputs `This is sentence one in a order This is sentence two in a order This is sentence Three in a order This is sentence four in a order` for that input.

Comment: Thank you for your response @glhr. I am sorry that I haven't explained you the problem clearly. From the below html content `<ul>
 <li>This is sentence one in a order</li>
 <li>This is sentence two in a order</li>
 <li>This is sentence 
  <em>Three</em> in a order
 </li>
 <li>This is sentence 
  <em>four</em> in a order
 </li>
</ul>`. I would like to get the above as separate sentences like "This is sentence one in a order, This is sentence two in a order, This is sentence three in a order, This is sentence four in a order". Here the problem arises in reading sentence 3 and 4.

Comment: You want the result as a list of strings you mean?

Comment: It gives me as a whole sentence. But i like to extract in way that it gives us the sentences separately

Comment: Yes, like each <li> as a sentence. the problem is while reading <em> tag in between. while using beautifulsoup it separates **sentence 3** as "This is sentence", "Three", "in a order". Like it separates the text into 3 sentences but it actually is a single sentence.

Comment: Edited my answer accordingly. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I really don't understand what you need , but It'll help you to extract Content from the url of the website

```
import requests
import xlsxwriter 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

#Text File where the content will be written
file = open("test.txt","w")

#Url from where the data will be extracted
urls ="https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/files/reading-and-writing-files-in-python"
page = requests.get(urls)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
for link in soup.find_all('p'): #extracting all content of <P> tag from the url
    #You can put the desired tag according to your need
 file.write(link.get_text())  
file.close()
```

Comment: Thank you. Hope my below comments explains you the problem clearly. Please find my comments added for @glhr 's answer